# How to make Django use the same session on different URLs?

Tags: django, session

How can we make Django use the same session on different URLs like app.example.com, example.com and www.example.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add [`SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/sessions/#session-cookie-domain) parameter to your settings

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.example.com'
```

> The domain to use for session cookies. Set this to a string such as ".lawrence.com" (note the leading dot!) for cross-domain cookies, or use None for a standard domain cookie.

Comment: Thanks Igor - This would make Django use same session on all URLs of the form *.example.com.

But if I want to keep app.example.com, example.com on one session
and
admin.example.com, owner.example.com on another session,
how can I achieve that?

Comment: If you have different django instances on different domains (i.e. they use different settings) - you can set different SESSION_COOKIE_NAME parameters. In other case you can overwrite `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware`